# Unable to run migrate command on command line and PIP freezes

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I am using python 3 and never installed python 2 on this PC. Trying to install and use Django. I was trying to use pip to download it but when I enter pip install django==1.8 on my command line, nothing happens. No error messages, no further information. Command line just seems to freeze.

I checked if my pip was installed by running import pip on my python shell and able to do it. I ended up downloading django and installing it via a .gz file. For checking, I tried using the python shell and able to import django.

I have now created a virtual environment and activated it and my command line looks as follows now:

(myenv) c:/....... thus am in my virtual environment.

I started a new project in using django-admin startproject mysite .

The mysite folder is created alone with a manage.py file.

Next up when I try to run the command python manage.py migrate  ,
I get the following error:

```
from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
ImportError: No module name 'django'
```

My manage.py file header is correct with the following line - `#!/usr/bin/env python`

Am I supposed to install django again in each individual virtual environment I create? If yes how do I do it since pip is jamming up.

Am I supposed to mess with environment variable PATH for this? Can someone help please. Went through similar cases here and none is helping.

Comment: Add your operating system, please. Did you try with `pip3 install django`? Did you try to re-install pip?

Comment: @LouisBarranqueiro Using windows. Tried with pip3 and it freezes too. Reinstaled pip and same results.

Comment: which version of windows? Maybe this can help you : [How to install pip on windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750806/how-to-install-pip-on-windows)

Comment: @LouisBarranqueiro Windows 10

Comment: It seems that there is a bug with python 3 on Windows 10. Try this to install your package : `python -m pip install package_name`. Does it work?

Comment: @LouisBarranqueiro says requirement already satisfied. Cos I already have django. Guess that means I have pip properly installed.

Comment: then install it in your virtualenv if that not already the case and try to start your server with `python manage.py runserver`

Comment: @LouisBarranqueiro So am I supposed to install django each time i create a new virtual enviroment?

Comment: yes, they have no access to packages installed globally. Is it working?

Comment: @LouisBarranqueiro says requirement satisfied when i try in virtual environment too. but the error is same when i try migrate after

Comment: in your virtual env : try to uninstall django with `python -m uninstall django` ,  re-install it and re-create a new project. If doesn't work. Try to do the same out of your virtual env

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> > Am I supposed to mess with environment variable PATH for this?

No.

> > Am I supposed to install django again in each individual virtual environment I create?

Yes.

> > If yes how do I do it since pip is jamming up?

Even if you develop in Windows, it is really good practice to keep your environment in a linux virtual machine, and use bash scripts to prepare it, so if something goes unexpected, you can easily destroy it and spin it up again. One way of doing so is installing VirtualBox + Vagrant.

One example of bash script is here: https://github.com/torchbox/vagrant-django-template

See the Vagrantfile, and etc/install.sh. Hope that helps.